# hdmi no signal, except with hdd/ssd unplugged and booting on live distribution

Tags: boot, kubuntu, display, hdmi

First of all I'm sorry for misspelling : I'm a non-native english speaker and I use a somewhat broken keyboard.

I use kubuntu 20.10. The computer was brand new a few weeks ago and worked perfectly. I turned it off a week ago, started it yesterday and took care of the available updates. Then I rebooted.

From that point, the computer started as usual but the screen remained blank. It used to do so until kubuntu booting (around ten seconds from the power up), so I never thought of this as an issue : it never displayed post, bios, grub etc... Nothing until the kubuntu booting splash-screen, either on the live flashdrive I used to install kubuntu or the installed os.

The screen works perfectly on another computer, both as primary and secondary screen. Another screen (working as well fine on other computers and laptops) displays nothing as well on this one.

The only way to have the screen displaying anything is to unplug both of my drives (one ssd with root and home, one hdd with personal data), plug in a flashdrive with a live distribution (gparted, kubuntu 20.10 and kubuntu 20.4.1 work fine) and let it boot. This setup displays the live os as it should do as long as I use the graphic board hdmi ports : the motherboard hdmi displays nothing, and if I unplug the graphic board I can't even boot on the flashdrive (I can tell by pressing the power button after a while : if the live boots, it displays a message asking to remove the drive before hitting enter ; with the graphic board unplugged, pressing this button switches off the computer right away).

No matter what I do or plug, the motherboard buzzer displays one long and two short beeps. I have no idea what they mean. I don't know if they were displayed before the boot issue because I plugged the buzzer in during my tests to solve the issue.

What I've tried so far :

- hit del (to enter bios) and/or f11 (to enter boot setup) from startup, with or without a flashdrive with live distribution, with or without the hard drives plugged, with two different keyboards and using three different usb ports
- try the other hdmi port on the graphic board, and the one on the motherboard
- reset the motherboard shortcutting the JBAT1 jumpers
- swap my power unit for another one
- start the computer with the graphic board unplugged (from both pcie and power)

If that is of any use, my computer is :

- msi a520m-a pro motherboard
- Aerocool Lux 550w power unit
- ryzen 3600 cpu
- amd radeon rx580 graphic card
- one ssd as root
- one hdd as data

I'm really running out of ideas. Someone pointed me that it may be related to the 5.8 kernel upgrade ([How do stop Ubuntu 20.04 from upgrading to the 5.8 hwe kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel/1306392)). I have no idea if the update I processed prior to the reboot and issue was this one, nor can I do anything about it right now (I can display graphical information only if I unplug my drives...).

Answer (score 0):

"*No matter what I do or plug, the motherboard buzzer displays one long and two short beeps.*"

You seem to be describing a hardware fault code, which is unrelated to Ubuntu. Contact your motherboard manufacturer to learn the meaning of the code.

Return your new equipment to the vendor for repair or replacement.

Ubuntu is not designed to run on broken or defective hardware.

Comment: Looks like it's a video issue :
https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm
https://www.lifewire.com/amibios-beep-codes-2624543

How can this kind of hardware issue could allow me to boot on a livecd without any trouble ?