# Internet dissapears after every linux kernel updates

Tags: networking, kernel, updates, internet

Recently it seems like the linux kernel minor version is updating a lot.  Every time it updates my internet completely disappears, wi-fi icon is gone, if I plug in an ethernet cable I get nothing, network menu shows nothing.   The first time it took all day to figure out.  Now every time the kernel updates, I have to do the following:

in grub menu, select the previous kernel from advanced options, e.g. today I booted into 5.8.0-40-generic, then ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-5.8.0-41-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then reboot as normal without advanced options and the world is back in order.  It happens about once a week at the moment.  Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

Not sure if this helps, but I did

```
lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

These drivers seem to be in the headers

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/arm64/linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic-64k/filelist

Next time it happens, I will run the command above and see if the kernel drivers are not found before doing the fixes.  I'll also try only doing the headers to see if that fixes it (so the extras module can maybe be excluded as a culprit)

Update:

For anyone experiencing this, using @Pilot6's suggestion below fixed the problem, the latest update had the hwe things in the download list and the kernel version updated with no problems!.  I found some more details about this here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do stop Ubuntu 20.04 from upgrading to the 5.8 hwe kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel)

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: @N0rbert not really, everything works fine after the above commands, so the kernel works when I re-install them.   So I suspect the headers or extra modules are not being installed correctly when the kernel updates.  Sometimes it happens during a live patch, all of a sudden all networking disappears until I take the above steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta package is not installed, that's why not all kernel package get upgrades.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

and it should be fixed.

Comment: thank you @Pilot6! I am trying this.  I will watch for the next kernel upgrade and if all is good, will close the issue