# Ubuntu focal kernel update

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kernel, updates

If I recall correctly, I installed my system from 20.04 desktop installation CD. I have been applying updates as they come along. However, even though I have seen many updates, I have not seen any updates for the kernel, which seems quite strange. Here's what I currently have

```
$ lsb_release --a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ uname -a
Linux abysss 5.4.0-64-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 10:27:54 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yubico/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libhidapi-hidraw0 libllvm10 libstartup-notification0 libu2f-host0 libu2f-server0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Can it really be true that there have been no updates to the kernel since January?

Comment: Do you mean January 2021? Kernels do not get updates a lot. There is a 5.8 which would have been installed on your system if you are letting the updates install. 5.11 is expected to be in the new 21.04 in late April.

Comment: I see you have only done update. The upgrade command actually upgrades and installs the latest versions of packages that are already installed. Before going to upgrade the packages, check for the updates as follows. It will let the apt-get to know the new versions available.

Comment: @David, yes I do mean no updates since January 15, 2021. It's now mid March and I'm surprised that there have not been any security updates. According to `dpkg -l |grep kernel | grep 5.8`, I do not see any 5.8 kernels on my system and I do not believe I did anything to prevent it from being installed. Does 20.04 LTS actually provide LTS support for multiple kernel versions at the same time?

Comment: On an Ubuntu LTS release, an LTS kernel version (such as 5.4 on Ubuntu 20.04), is usually used. While the major kernel version (5.x) is not often updated, instead, security updates and bugfixes for the current kernel are released (e.g. 5.4.0-xx). Alternatively, if you want a more up-to-date kernel, you can either upgrade to the interim release of Ubuntu (currently 20.10), or install a mainline kernel from the [Ubuntu kernel ppa](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Comment: Some users are forced to use the 5.4 kernel as the 5.8 does not work with their hardware. So yes.

Comment: You may find the answers to this question interesting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel

Comment: Please add to your question the complete output of `sudo apt upgrade` also.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg LTS releases get newer kernels backported via HWE. See [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). Can you please confirm if you have `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` installed?

Comment: One possibility is that you simply have not rebooted in many weeks. what's your `uptime`? My own frequently runs to 2-3 months before it occurs to me to reboot.

Comment: @Kulfy - according to `dpkg -l |grep linux-generic-hwe` I do not have it installed. But why should I need `HWE`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to know why your system doesn't have a newer kernel. Is that right? If yes, please re-read my previous comment.